# nginx proxy_pass error: upstream 127.0.0.1 works, but aaa.com not

Tags: nginx

I want proxy_pass some request location to an upstream server, here is my nginx.conf:

```
upstream bar {
    server 127.0.0.1:25501;
    #server aaa.com:25501;
}

server {
    listen  80;

    location /api {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://bar;
    }
}
```

If server is set to `127.0.0.1:25501`, it works. If server is set to `aaa.com` which point to the same server, it failed with `upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out)`.

Is there anything wrong?